# How to get the wsdl file from a webservice's URL

Tags: wsdl

I want to get the WSDL file for a webservice and the only thing I have is its URL (like webservice.example/foo).

If I use the URL directly only an error response is delivered.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

By postfixing the URL with `?WSDL`

If the URL is for example:

```
http://webservice.example:1234/foo
```

You use:

```
http://webservice.example:1234/foo?WSDL
```

And the wsdl will be delivered.

Comment: All caps sometimes as well (WSDL)

Comment: And if you don't get the wsdl you may get an xml with a binding key or some sort of validation code that will help you to compose the actual url of the wsdl.

Comment: Any idea how to get the imported xsd files?

Comment: This doesn't work.    This is my web service url:   https://prealert-test.customer-pages.com

Comment: The ?WSDL thingy is a convention usually followed by frameworks and so. If it's not working for you I guess you should find something specific for the framework you are using.

Answer (score 39):

#### to get the `WSDL` (`Web Service Description Language`) from a Web Service URL.

Is possible from SOAP Web Services:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx
```

to get the WSDL we have only to add **`?WSDL`** , for example:

[http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?**WSDL**](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL)

Comment: How would u retrieve some data, using the url?

Comment: If you want to retrieve data from SOAP you should use this tool https://www.soapui.org/ it is free and works fine.

Answer (score 18):

Its only possible to get the WSDL if the webservice is configured to deliver it. Therefor you have to specify a serviceBehavior and enable httpGetEnabled:

```xml
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BindingBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

In case the webservice is only accessible via https you have to enable http**s**GetEnabled instead of httpGetEnabled.

Answer (score 12):

To download the wsdl from a url using **Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio**, run it in Administrator mode and enter the following command:

```
 svcutil /t:metadata http://[your-service-url-here]
```

You can now consume the downloaded wsdl in your project as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

1. explore the url + ?wsdl:

   `http://localhost:1234/sevice.aspx?WSDL`
2. right-click on the page and select Save As...
3. Select XML format and click Save.