# In SSIS using the web service task: Can I convert a website to WSDL file?

Tags: ssis, wsdl

In SSIS, what I would like to do is use the Web service task to retrieve data from a website. The website is called [yahoo fantasy basketball](https://basketball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/nba/9720/players). How can I convert this website into a WSDL file?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [ask] a question.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the wsdl file from a webservice's URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742589/how-to-get-the-wsdl-file-from-a-webservices-url)