# Using C# SDK for IIS, is there a way to query a web service and detect which methods it has?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I'm able to query an IIS with the IIS SDK and detect which application are installed in the IIS.

```
        foreach (Site site in sites)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Site: " + site.Name);

            foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Binding Information: " + binding.BindingInformation);
            }

            foreach (Application app in site.Applications)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("App Path: " + app.Path);
            }
           
        }
```

My applications are web services (asmx and wcf). Is there a way to query each application and detect which methods are published?

What I need is the full URL of the webservice.

Is there a way to do it without the IIS SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: In ASMX _specifically_, **yes** it is possible, because ASMX has WSDL support built-in (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742589/how-to-get-the-wsdl-file-from-a-webservices-url/54127727 ) - but for others, it depends (WCF has MEX, and RESTful services (e.g. in ASP.NET Core) _can_ expose a Swagger JSON file, but this not enabled by default - however you still need to know the path to the `.asmx` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

An application can have multiple urls based on number of bindings.

So you can use these properties to get the relevant information in your `foreach` loop.

```
binding.Host
binding.Endpoint.Address 
binding.Endpoint.Port
```

Based on these properties you can form the applications base urls.

Comment: Thanks, but the result is a URL that does not include the method of the web service.
This will give me this URL:
http://myHost:1234/MyWebService
While I need this:
http://myHost:1234/MyWebService/Calculate

Comment: @kruvi as far as I know, that is not possible.